# What does it mean to get an "-e" value when listing installed packages with pip freeze?

Tags: python, git, pip

I just created a new virtual environment in my Windows 8 box, I have not installed any package yet. After activating the new virtual environment, if I do a pip freeze, I get a weird reference to a github project. What does that mean? How do I get rid of it?

```
(my_virtual_env) C:\>pip freeze
-e git+git@github.com:my_repo.git@221689bbe130338b04a2d837ebe69a9ccc695f8a#egg=my_repo-origin/my_branch
```

Comment: It means the package is installed in **e**ditable mode, see e.g. https://pip.pypa.io/en/latest/reference/pip_install.html#editable-installs

Comment: But I don't recall having installed that, how do I get rid of it? I tried using pip uninstall -e git+git... with no luck

Comment: It's _your_ repo -- so a project you're personally working on/with, right? Maybe you ran `python setup.py develop` in the source tree?

Comment: Anyhow, details of how you remove it depend on how it's installed. It might be an `.egg-link` file in your site-packages directory, it might be an entry in a `.pth` file in that same directory... there's no point to us playing guessing games here.

Comment: Thanks for your answers @Charles Duffy I installed it (in a different virtual environment) by doing python setup.py install while I was testing my setup.py file... but it now shows in all the virtual environments that I create.

Comment: Clearly, then, it _didn't_ get installed confined to a virtualenv as you'd intended. Check inside your site-packages for your main Python install -- not the virtualenv -- for a related `.pth` file entry, `.egg-link`, or direct subdirectory contents.

Answer (score 2):

If you want new virtualenvs to be completely clean, then use:

```
virtualenv --no-site-packages new-virtualenv-name
```

...when generating them. Otherwise, they contain all packages installed in your main Python installation (outside any virtualenv).